# Share a dictionary within a C# windows form

Tags: c#, button, dictionary, event-handling, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with a series of buttons. 
button4 has to load some data from Excel and store the information into a dictionary called dataMap

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        loadXL myMap = new loadXL();
        Dictionary<string, marketdata> dataMap = myMap.myDataLoader(Convert.ToDateTime(AsOfDate.Text),Convert.ToDouble(Underlying.Text));
    }
```

This code generates correctly the dictionary and all the data I need are stored in ***dataMap***. Now the problem is that I need the information in the dictionary to be accessible when I click another button. 
In order to do that I have tried the following:

```
    public Dictionary<string, marketdata> button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        loadXL myMap = new loadXL();
        Dictionary<string, marketdata> dataMap = myMap.myDataLoader(Convert.ToDateTime(AsOfDate.Text),Convert.ToDouble(Underlying.Text));

        return dataMap;
    }
```

So the click button event now should return the dictionary ***dataMap***. If I run this I get the following error:

> *'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary Project2.myInputForm.button4_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' has the
>   wrong return type*

and it refers to the following line in the form designer:

```
    this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
```

How can I handle this? Is there a quick way to make the dictionary built when clicking button4 accessible by other button clicks?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you have "public Dictionary<string, marketdata> button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) "  onclick events are not expected to have any return value which results in your error. Should the same dictionary be available to all onclicks in the same class or in multiple classes? (a private variable containing the dictionary would be a possible solution then if the former is the case)

Comment: Basically by clicking this button I want to load the data in the dictionary. Then I have another button that has to use the information in the dictionary created by clicking button4 (the previous button). So far all this is happening inside the same form but it would be good to have access to this dictionary also from other forms if needed.

Comment: opt: with load do you mean ADD to or replace the content of the dictionary? (the answers I see below are having the replace variant in mind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, marketdata> dataMap;
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    loadXL myMap = new loadXL();
    dataMap = myMap.myDataLoader(Convert.ToDateTime(AsOfDate.Text),Convert.ToDouble(Underlying.Text));
}

private void function()
{

    dataMap.//
}
```

Declare it outside and then use it whenever just make sure you dont use it before its instantiated

Answer (score 1):

Button click event cannot return anything, the return type should be void

You should create  a property at your form level and access it in click events of the buttons

for example

```
Dictionary<string, marketdata> dataMap;
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    loadXL myMap = new loadXL();
    dataMap = myMap.myDataLoader(Convert.ToDateTime(AsOfDate.Text),Convert.ToDouble(Underlying.Text));
}

private void anotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (dataMap != null)
    {
        // here you can access dataMap
    }
}
```

### Edit

If you want to access the dictionary variable from multiple forms then you should create another class which should contain the public property to be accessible from multiple places.

```
public class MyStaticProperties
{
    public static Dictionary<string, marketdata> DataMap { get; set; };
}

// then you can access this in your button click events like htis
MyStaticProperties.DataMap
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an example how to use the dictionary across multiple forms.

Comment: You will use this line to access the dictionary in multiple forms `MyStaticProperties.DataMap`